# How to compare chars in loop only for specific range

Tags: java, loops, char, compare

i´ve got two char[] which looks like u4[] `111111111733333333322211111111111111111117333333` and u5[] `3333333222111111111111111111111173333333333333333` . So now i want to compare these two chars and want to write the specific values into a variable. (t2 is the factor,which values should be compared! that means,that u5[0] should be compared with u4[12],u5[ 1 ] with u4[13] and so on - so just say,that t2 = 12)

So i have worked with the following code:

```js
if(u4[e] == '7' && u4[e+1] != '7') 
 { y10 =  e+1; 
  y00 = y10 - t2;    
  if(u5[(e+1)-(int)t2] == '3')
                 {y00 = y10 - t2; 
          for(int z = (e+1)-(int)t2;z<u4.length;z++)
                  {if((u5[z] != '3') && (u5[z-1] == '3') && (u4[z+(int)t2] == '3'))
                       {     y01 = z-1; 
        y11 = y01 + t2;
         }
   else{}
         }
           }  
       
  double[] coord = {x0,y00,x1,y10,x1,y11,x0,y01};
  XYPolygonAnnotation Polygon = new XYPolygonAnnotation(coord, new BasicStroke(new Float(0.01)), Color.BLACK, Color.LIGHT_GRAY);               
                Plot.addAnnotation(Polygon);
         }
 else{}
```

So the target is,to get polygon for each conjunction between the values '3' ! so like the following pictures. (u5 is at x axis = 570 and u4 is at x axis 730, so i´m just interested in the right half)

[Generated manual -> so it should be!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkl1l.jpg)

[Generated by loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM4Hh.jpg)

So if you can see,i only want to make a polygon between the "green" (='3') values on BOTH chars! That means,that i want to consider only the area with "green" at u5[] and compare with "green" at u4[]..is that not possible(maybe u4[] is "red" in this searched area, than i want to go to the next "green" section at u5[] and so on...so i´m not interested in the "red" areas...but the loop is going over each value-of course,that is the task of a loop- and so i also got some bigger,useless polygons!
Does anyone has an idea,how to constrict the loop for only the "green" areas?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: yes you are right,sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess:  the innermost `else` case, whose code is empty, should have `break;`.  Otherwise, the loop just keeps going after finding the boundary between 3 and not 3.